# Como criar um filtro para um array multidimenssional mixed

Tags: php, array-multidimensional, filter, array-associativo, sanitize

Tenho no meu POST variáveis complexas com arrays dentro de outros arrays e etc.
Veja:

```
$filtro['esms_conta_id'] = 120;
$filtro['data_inicio'] = 2016-010-1;
$filtro['data_final'] = 2016-010-1;
$filtro['status']['accepted'] = true;
$filtro['status']['pending'] = true;
$filtro['status']['undeliverable'] = false;
$filtro['status']['delivered'] = false;
$filtro['status']['expired'] = true;
$filtro['status']['rejected'] = false;
```

preciso fazer um filtro bem simples como na função abaixo.

```
public static function filter_post_feedback_controller() {
    $args = array(
        'flag_feedback'     => FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH,
        'assunto'           => FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH,
        'nome'              => FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH,
        'email'             => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL,
        'feedback'          => FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH
    );

    return $args;

}
```

Comment: Veja se [isso te ajuda](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/arrayiterator.valid.php).